# Regex to find an excerpt of a text 4 words before and 4 words after the text but only take one excerpt

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regex that will match for only one keyword in a text including 4 words before and 4 words after.

I am currently using `(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,4}keyword(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,4}` but that will capture multiple excerpts containing the keyword when i only want to match one result.

for example putting the text "`I am hoping to find four words before a keyword and four words after the same word to show in the description for the result and if there is another keyword then i dont want to capture that`"

It will match with "four words before a keyword and four words after" and "if there is another keyword then i dont want" i only want the first match.

Comment: Don't use `global` flag. I don't know which tool you're using by default, but, for instance, in `sed` do not use `g` in `sed -ne 's/regex/replacement/g'`.

Comment: [Works for me](https://regex101.com/r/bWv4FO/1)

Comment: You must tell us which tool or language you are using for us to be able to answer your question. Please add the tag of the language/tool to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use PCRE pattern with `\K` that cuts off text matched before:

```
(?s)^.*?\K(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,4}keyword(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,4}
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/nazDnQ/1)

Alternative with a capturing group (you need captured value):

```
(?s)^.*?((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,4}keyword(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,4})
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/nazDnQ/2). You may need to use a specific function, or code to access that value.